# How to redirect Tomcat app to custom port with nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx

**tl;dr**

Now my app is on `http://<some_ip>:5001/<app_name>/` i just want to redirect it to `http://<some_ip>:<my_custom_port>/`without moving my app to ROOT directory in tomcat. I need to cutoff the `<app_name>` from link

I end up with this configuration

```
server {
    listen <my_custom_port>;

    server_name <some_ip>;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/<app_name>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat conf/server.xml has a configuration for for docBase. Using this configuration, the redirection can be done to http://some_ip:5001 for the specific app.

```
<Context docBase="app name" path="/" reloadable="true"/>
```

The context configuration goes under

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context docBase="app name" path="/" reloadable="true"/> 
</Host>
```

With the above configuration, you don't need to move your app to the ROOT directory.